# PHP IMAP email body decode issue

Tags: php, email, imap

I am working on my PHP to store the emails in the sent folder. I have got a problem with storing the url in the emails, because I will be getting `id` and `msgid` in the img tag src when it should be `id=` and `msgid=`. I have been researching for hours and I couldn't be able to find out how to store the `=` in the html as I keep getting the  and  when I store the emails in the sent folder.

When I try this:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

// Connect to the server:
$username = 'myusername';
$password = '*************';

$sent = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent';
$sent_mailbox = imap_open($sent, $username, $password);

$from_email = $_POST['send_from'];
$to_email = $_POST['send_to'];
$subject = $_POST['emailsubject'];
$message = '<div id="emailMessage" class="row" style="padding: 5px 30px;margin-top: 12px;"><div><div dir="ltr"><img src="http://example.com/u/?id=1562453336&amp;attid=0.2&amp;msgid=1644988591229814716&amp;view=attachment&amp;display=view" width="452" height="302" class="CToWUd a6T" tabindex="0"><br><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><img src="http://example.com/u/?id=1562453336&amp;attid=0.1&amp;msgid=1644988591229814716&amp;view=attachment&amp;display=view" class="CToWUd"><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>
```

';

```
$messageID = sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
        base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
        base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
        'example.com');


imap_append($sent_mailbox, $sent,
    "From: ".$from_email."r\n".
    "To: ".$to_email."\r\n".
    "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
    "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
    "Message-ID: ".$messageID."\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1 \r\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary1\"\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    "--$boundary1\r\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$boundary2\"\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    // ADD Plain text data
    "--$boundary2\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    $message."\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    // ADD Html content
    "--$boundary2\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    $message."\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    "--$boundary1\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    // ADD attachment(s)
    $attachment1.
    "\r\n\r\n".
    "--$boundary1--\r\n\r\n",
    "\\Seen"
 );
```

Here is what it will show  next to the id and  next to the msgid like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/u/?id62453336&amp;attid=0.2&amp;msgid44988591229814716&amp;view=attachment&amp;display=view" width="452" height="302" class="CToWUd a6T">
```

I have tried this:

```
$message = html_entity_decode($message);
```

And I have also tried this:

```
$message = htmlspecialchars($message);
```

It doesn't make any difference so I dont know what to do.

Can you please show me an example of what I should use to store the html emails in the sent folder when I have the `id=` and `msgid=` in the img tag url without display the  and ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using quoted printable, you need to escape your equals (=3D)

Comment: @Max Thank you it is working great. Could you please post the answer so I can mark as a answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using quoted printable, you need to escape your equals signs(=3D).

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this

```
$message= nl2br($message);
```

Comment: HemantKumar huh? the code is using for a break, I dont want a break the lines. I want to use something to decode to avoid the apostrophe strings display

Comment: this might helps https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-convert-special-html-entities-back-to-characters-in-php.php